# Unable to add shape to array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to declare a new shape Square and later will add a circle, to the same array Shape which is an abstract class.

I'm a bit confused since I'm not getting any errors but the program is just crashing (but works when the code is removed)

Main:

```
#include "Shape.h"
#include "Square.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {   
    Shape *shapesArray[6];
    Square *s;
    s->setValues(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);
    shapesArray[0] = s;

    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Square.cpp:

```
#include "Square.h"

void Square::setValues(float w, float x, float y, float z){
    this->w = w;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
}
```

Square.h:

```
#include "Shape.h"

using namespace std;

class Square: public Shape
{
    float w,x,y,z;

public:
    void setValues(float,float,float,float);
    Square();
};
```

Shape.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Shape {
public:
    // pure virtual function providing interface framework.
    virtual int getArea() = 0;
    Shape();

protected:
    int radius;
    float x;
    float y;
    float w;
    float z;
};
```

Comment: `Square *s` is _a simple pointer_. It doesn't point to _anything_ since you never initialise it. So, calling `s->setValues` will crash. In C++ it's the programmer's job to allocate memory!

Comment: Thank you for providing all your code, but please in the future, indent it readably, [not like this](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41088191/1).

Comment: Please also note that `using namespace std` is bad practice, and using it in a header file is extremely bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Square *s;
```

This doesn't cause `s` to point to anything in particular. Using the value of `s` in this state is *undefined behaviour*. You have to initialize `s` before you can use it.

Normally you would initialize it like this:

```
Square *s = new Square;
```

however if you do that, you will find out that you have an unresolved reference error. Please read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) about this error. Meanwhile you can just remove these lines:

```
Square();
Shape();
```

When you feel your classes need a constructor, add them back, with definitions. Note that a constructor is a vastly superior alternative to a function like `setValues`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise a Square object by calling `Square* s = new Square();` in Main at line 9. In your code, there is no object instance yet, so that you cannot call a function such as `s->setValues(1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f);`. `s` here is just a pointer that points to no meaningful memory location.